# gephi 0.8.2 failed to recognise the number of nodes and edges

Tags: dot, gephi

I used java to generate some dot files, but Gephi 0.82 can only open some of them correctly. For some files, it showed 0 for the number of edges and nodes and no other error information. In fact, Gvedit can open them correctly.  The following is a failed file:

```
digraph G {
 ranksep=.25;
 edge [arrowsize=.5]
 node [shape=box, fontsize=10, fixedsize=false, height=.45];
 "acc_spec/5"; "edcg_error/2"; "loading_file_position/1"; "acc_name/5"; "is_acc_name/1"; "loading_module/1"; "acc_default_init_value/2"; "make_accs_frame/4"; "acc_direction/2"; 
 "acc_spec/5" -> "edcg_error/2";
 "edcg_error/2" -> "loading_file_position/1";
 "acc_spec/5" -> "acc_name/5";
 "acc_name/5" -> "edcg_error/2";
 "acc_name/5" -> "is_acc_name/1";
 "is_acc_name/1" -> "loading_module/1";
 "acc_name/5" -> "acc_default_init_value/2";
 "acc_default_init_value/2" -> "loading_module/1";
 "acc_name/5" -> "make_accs_frame/4";
 "make_accs_frame/4" -> "acc_direction/2";
 "acc_direction/2" -> "loading_module/1";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs with Gephi 0.82. After I checked out the latest source code from its github repository, compiled it and ran, the number of nodes and of edges are both correct.

the checked-out version is 0.9-snapshot master with netbeans 7.4.